# How to automate same testclass in different location and variable for different Countries

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to figure out something like below mentioned and need to automate:-

Lets assume I have 2 countries and 2 browser and 4 devices to test and only have one test class for login page.
User id and password are same for both the locations. Only changes are in desired capabilities (device id, name).I do not want to hardcode the location and browser into the test class so I created another one which holds the variable.
So i have created Constants.java page and mentioned like below details

public static String Location = “XX”;

public static String Location = “YY”;

In the test class I would call it example

However every time i have to change the location manually in Constants page.

My Question is how can I select before I start the test the other browser or location without always changing the code at the testclass(ex-Constants.java page ).

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do it. I think using properties or json file is a good option.

- Since you mentioned changing browser and location, I suggest create file for each device:

e.g. `Xaomi_Redmi9.properties` with content:

```
browserName=chrome
location=Poland
```

- add logic to [read properties file](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) and use that function before you create Appium session
- if you use maven to run tests, you can pass device file via console:

`mvn clean test -Ddevice=Xaomi_Redmi9`

and read it in your code like

`String devicesPropsFile = System.getProperty("device") + ".properties"`

It is quick and dummy example, but hope you helps to find out what works for you